# Integrating Docker with jenkins for continuous integration

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have jenkins to compile and build the artifacts. I cannot install docker and create containers in the jenkins machine, so i have installed docker in separate machine say 192.000.000.1. From jenkins i need to execute the dockerfile available in 192.000.000.1 (where docker is installed). Can anyone please explain me how to accomplish this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Adding a Jenkins slave on 192.0.0.1 and using https://github.com/ndeloof/docker-slaves-plugin might do the trick

Comment: how about this http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/?